# Round decimal number to positive infinity in c# in Net Standard library

Tags: c#, rounding, .net-standard-2.1

I am trying to round up decimal numbers towards positive infinity in C# .Net Standard 2.1 library using  `Math.Round()` function with `MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity` enum as its mode parameter but I don't know why it doesn't exist in the MidpointRounding enum. the same enum value (`ToPositiveInfinity`) exists when the project is using .net 5.
Code

```
Math.Round(2.336, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity);
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: The [`MidpointRounding` enum in .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netstandard-2.1) only has `AwayFromZero` and `ToEven`. The other modes, such as `ToPositiveInfinity`, were added later, in .NET Core 3.0. You can't use functionality which doesn't exist (in the runtime you're targetting), unless you implement it yourself.

Comment: @canton7 Do you have any idea that how I can implement it?

Comment: @Fouad `Math.Floor(x+0.5)`

Comment: @DStanley, it returns an integral value. I need a upward rounded decimal value with two decimal places. Ex: 1.232 => 1.24 | 1.261 => 1.27 | 1.251 => 126 | 1.350 => 1.350

Comment: @Fouad If all of your inputs are positive, just use `.AwayFromZero`. `.ToPositiveInfinity` and `.AwayFromZero` only differ if the input is negative

Comment: @Fouad `Math.Floor(x * Math.Pow(10,decimals) + 0.5) / Math.Pow(10,decimals))`

Comment: @canton7 Can't negative inputs be handled by changing sign before and after rounding `.AwayFromZero`? `public static double RoundToPositiveInfinity(double num, int decimals) =>
 (num < 0) ? -Math.Round(-num, decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
 : Math.Round(num, decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
`

Comment: @NetMage I would have thought so

Comment: Thanks @NetMage but your solution is not rounding to positive infinity.

Comment: @canton7 thanks yes inputs are positive numbers but AwayFromZero and ToPositiveInfinity are different. If you test these two approaches on my examples in the fourth comment fr top you will notice the difference.

Comment: Ah, `ToPositiveInfinity` and `ToNegativeInfinity` and `ToZero` aren't actually *midpoint* rounding strategies, despite the enum name. They don't control how we round at the midpoint (e.g. 2.5), they control whether we ceiling or floor the value. That's very confusing. Ignore what I said earlier.

Comment: In that case, `ToPositiveInfinity` is the same as `Math.Ceiling`. So `Math.Ceiling(2.336 * 100) / 100` or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MidpointRounding` enum in .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netstandard-2.1) only has `AwayFromZero` and `ToEven`. The other modes, such as `ToPositiveInfinity`, were added later, in .NET Core 3.0. You can't use functionality which doesn't exist (in the runtime you're targetting), unless you implement it yourself.

However, `ToPositiveInfinity` does the same thing as `Math.Ceiling`, so you can use that. `Math.Ceiling` however doesn't support specifying the number of decimal places to round to, but you can overcome that with a little multiplication:

```
Math.Ceiling(2.336 * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: I would speculate that for some precisions there could be a different answer between `ToPositiveInfinity` and `Math.Ceiling`, but not at two places.

Comment: @NetMage Would you provide an example?

Comment: In addition to @canton7's answer following extension method will support all decimal places, --- public static decimal ToPositiveInfinity(this decimal value, int decimals)
        {
            var decimalPlaces = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, decimals));
            return Math.Ceiling(value * decimalPlaces) / decimalPlaces;
        }